# Getting form inputs in the controller after validation

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel world and I have a problem which I can't solve so far.

My question is:
How to access the submitted values in the controller's `create()` function after the validation fails?

Here is what I have:

1. PostsController, defined as resource in the routes.php
2. In the controller I have usual methods `create()` and `store()` etc.

Here is some code:

```
//PostsController
public function create()
{
    //Here I need to get the inputs
    return view('posts.create');
}

public function store(Requests\PostsRequest $request)
{
    //store actions
}
```

I have created PostsRequest class which has some rules like:

```
public function rules(){
    $rules = [
        'category_id'=>'required',
        'name'=>'required|min:3',
        'description'=>'required'
    ];
    return $rules;
}
```

If everything is fine the entry has been stored to the DB, but when the validation fails, it's loaded the `create()` with some validation messages. 
I need to load ancestors of the selected category in the form and this should happen by knowing the submitted value of the `category_id` element.

What I've tried so far:

1. Tried to add parameter in the create like so:

   ```
   public function create(Requests\PostsRequest $request){...}
   ```

   But it went to infinite loop. I understand why because of the resource definition of the controller and it "think" that it's store method.
2. Tried to print facade `Input::all()` but it's empty
3. Tried to make:

   ```
   public function create(){
       $request = new \Request();
       //print $request
   }
   ```

   But it doesn't work, neither I think it's the right way.

So any idea how to get these values in the controller would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `{!! Form::open() !!}` (or `Form::model`) everything will be loaded again (after redirect back). Laravel automatically capture the "Input::old" values.

**From source: FormBuilder.php (illuminate/html package - Version 5.0)**

```
/**
 * Get the value that should be assigned to the field.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
public function getValueAttribute($name, $value = null)
{
    if (is_null($name)) return $value;

    if ( ! is_null($this->old($name)))
    {
        return $this->old($name);
    }

    if ( ! is_null($value)) return $value;

    if (isset($this->model))
    {
        return $this->getModelValueAttribute($name);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use illuminate/html, just add at your  value attribute:

```
Input::old('input_name')
```

---

If you want to get the Request. Just add to your create method.

```
public function create(Request $request){
   $data = $request->all(); //or whatever you want..
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment to the other answer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the data with Input::old()

In your views you can do

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" />
```

which would give the value from name if it was sent.

Also see this recent question/answer;
[Laravel 5 - Validation error on form doesn't re-enter user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735303/laravel-5-validation-error-on-form-doesnt-re-enter-user-input?rq=1)

Comment: My problem is not to display the value in the field, but to get it somehow in the controller. I have lot of nested categories, and I need to display them as multiple selects for each level. When user select category from the level 3, and validation fails I need to load 2 more levels in order to display the current selection, which by the way is loaded with ajax (e.g. select cat1, (load new select) then select cat1.2, (load new select) then select.